# Rename dataframe columns using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change my dataframe columns names , i tried two methods but none of them worked .
here is my code ;

method 1 :

```
def func():   
    energy=pd.ExcelFile('Energy Indicators.xls').parse('Energy')
    energy=energy.iloc[16:][['Environmental Indicators: Energy','Unnamed:3','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 5']].copy() energy.columns()=['Country',
    'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '%Renewable']
return energy
```

method 2:

```
def func():
    energy=pd.ExcelFile('Energy Indicators.xls').parse('Energy')
    energy=energy.iloc[16:][['Environmental Indicators: Energy','Unnamed: 3','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 5']].copy()

    return energy.rename(columns={'Environmental Indicators: Energy': 'Country', 'Unnamed: 3': 'Energy Supply',
                                  'Unnamed: 4': 'Energy Supply per Capita', 'Unnamed: 5': '% Renewable'}, inplace=True)
```

Both of them return a NoneType Object .

Here is the .xls file i'm working on : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B80lepon1RrYeDRNQVFWYVVENHM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in method 1, try to change `energy.columns()` to `energy.columns`:

```
energy.columns =['Country','Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '%Renewable']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `inplace=True` argument modifies the data frame in place, meaning it won't return anything as a result of the operation.

You can either:
- Return the `.rename()` without `inplace=True`, or
- Don't return anything and use the pass-by-reference property to make the update.